# GTM look for text on page every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript

Google Tag Manager (GTM) - I'm trying to use the following custom javascript variable to look for specific text on a page every 5 seconds but getting the error *"Error at line 12, character 1: Parse error. ')' expected"* whenever I try to preview the container, code below:

```
function YouThank() {
var content = document.body.innerText;
var query="thank you";
if (content.search(query) > -1 ) {
 return true;
} else {
 return false;
}
   setTimeout(YouThank, 5000);
}
YouThank();
```

Comment: For one thing, Custom JavaScript variables most be anonymous functions, so you can't use a name. This also means you can't call it like `YouThank()`. Maybe use a custom HTML tag for this instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you cal the set timeout function inside the YouThank. you just place this function outside the function.